# Error install grunt-cli using npm

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am getting the following error when installing grunt using npm nodejs.  Can someone tell what it is trying have problems with and how I can fix it.  We do have firewall so is there another way to download grunt and install? I a newbie and just getting my feet wet.

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.26 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\testuser>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: 12812:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
 protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:766:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at SlabBuffer.use (tls.js:232:18)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:452:29)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
npm ERR!     at flow (_stream_readable.js:592:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:624:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
 ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\testuser
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\testuser\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

thank you
Nick